# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am getting this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.class

Here is my Dependencies. I am using OkHttp for Network Operation. It works perfect in 5.0 and above. but below this it gives this error.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-18-0.8.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/bugsense-3.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.1.0-beta-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/glide-3.6.1.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.0'
    compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    }
```

The whole gridle is as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.onesnaps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
 }
```

There is no error while gradle sync. At run it throws this error for device below lollipop.

Comment: You are adding twice the same class: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.class

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have only add         compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar') for apache. I think, no any other dependency for it. Can you please tell more about my mistake.

Comment: May be the same class is also in another jar file.

Comment: This may happen, but it works fine for Lollipop & Marshmallow. I have also removed compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar') in dependencies.  What to do!

Comment: HI, Issue has been solved by adding this code in Application class.. `@Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
 }` Thanks

Comment: i tried above suggestion still having same issue. How to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> duplicate entry: **org/apache/commons**/codec/binary/Base64.class

...

> It works perfect **in 5.0 and above**

It sounds like you might be coming across this problem:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

> Note: The android:required="false" attribute is required for apps that have a minimum SDK of 23 or lower, because on devices with API levels lower than 24, **the org.apache.http.legacy library is not available. (On those devices, the Apache HTTP classes are available on the bootclasspath.**)

Therefore, you do not need the dependency

```
     compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
```

when you are compiling for the lower versions of Android.

---

OR

> app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex

You might be over the method count limit and need to enable multidex

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex as mentioned in the comments [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400943/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-bas/56902881#comment60424388_36400943)